# How does asp.net mvc 6 knows what resources to add when a controller does not inherith from Controller class?

Tags: clr, roslyn, visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core-mvc

I startted studing the internals from asp.net mvc (6/vnext) and I have a lot of questions but I would like to keep one here. I am using Visual Studio 2015 preview and I saw a new feature in asp.net mvc 6 (or vNext) that controller are not required to inherith from `Controller` base class. I saw in the asp.net mvc 4/5 the Controller class (or its abstractions) has the properties for resources like `TempData`, `ViewData`, `ViewBag` and method like `View()`, `Json()`, `File()` etc.

Now, in the new version, we are not required to inherit from the `Controller` base class. So, my question is, *how does asp.net mvc knows what resources to add when a controller does not inherit from `Controller` class?* I saw we can add a property and it will be resolved at runtime but how is it done in the asp.net core? Is there a IoC working inside the asp.net core to resolve it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

MVC 6 locates controllers based on a type being public and ending with the suffix `Controller`. The reality is a bit more complicated than that, and it's also customizable to support other conventions, but that's the essence of it.

Beyond that, MVC 6 has a system to "hydrate" a controller (and views, and other specific types) with required data. This is mostly done with the `[Activate]` attribute that tells MVC to call into the dependency injection system to populate dependencies on an instance of a class. You can even see in the built-in `Controller` base class how this is done:

https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/2353bd911ac137e7858de5bef88af8f7eccaa49f/src/Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Core/Controller.cs#L92L99

```
namespace Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc
{
    public class Controller : ...
    {
        ...

        [Activate]
        public ActionContext ActionContext { get; set; }

        [Activate]
        public IUrlHelper Url { get; set; }

        [Activate]
        public IActionBindingContextProvider BindingContextProvider { get; set; }

        ...
    }
}
```

This is triggered by `DefaultControllerFactory` here:

https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/2eef4dd3cf2964136dea9a144b1ee8c21df25c23/src/Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Core/DefaultControllerFactory.cs#L41

```
_controllerActivator.Activate(controller, actionContext);
```

And that uses an `IControllerActivator`, and in particular, the `DefaultControllerActivator` that scans for the `[Activate]` attribute and assigns values to the properties:

https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/c16214a53db7f16b06fd9b5a59fa1541e8ecd87a/src/Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Core/DefaultControllerActivator.cs

Comment: Do you know what part of ControllerFActory I can see where it is resolved by the core?